# Запрос с использованием LIKE и NOT IN

Tags: mysql

Есть такой вот запрос:

```
SELECT `inpoint` FROM `u_prof` WHERE `inpoint`!='' AND `inpoint` NOT IN ('".implode(",", $usedInpoints)."') GROUP BY `inpoint`
```

Т.е. на вход подается массив `$usedInpoints` и с ним сравнивается. А как можно переделать запрос так, чтобы было не строгое сравнение, а через LIKE, типа:

```
NOT LIKE IN ('%".implode(",", $usedInpoints)."%')
```

Comment: Какого типа поле `inpoint` в таблице `u_prof` и что из себя представляют элементы массива ` $usedInpoints`

Comment: inpoint - varchar, элементы массива - наборы символов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по выражениям SQL выражение предназаначается для PHP, тогда можно так:

```
$where = array("`inpoint`!=''");
foreach ($usedInpoints as $_) {
    $where[] = "`inpoint` NOT LIKE '%$_%'";
}
$sql =
    "SELECT `inpoint` FROM `u_prof` WHERE "
    . implode(" AND ", $where)
    . "GROUP BY `inpoint`";
```

Comment: То, что нужно, Спасибо! Просто я думал можно как то одним лайком обойтись.