# sql сравнение чисел как LIKE строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица вида {id, name}, в которой id может принимать большие значения, например, 17200, 17201, 17202, 17203 и т.д.
Подскажите, пожалуйста такой запрос, чтобы по части id, например, 1720, выводил соответствующие ему строки, например, id=1720, 17200, 17201 и т.д

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос с использованием LIKE и NOT IN](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65018/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-like-%d0%b8-not-in)

Answer (score 1):

*MySQL*:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) LIKE '123%'
;
```

*DB Fiddle*: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8fEWpnBpU1CqZ6SEJyiSD3/0.

*PostgreSQL* и *SQLite*:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE CAST(id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '123%'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать **[CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)**

```
... WHERE CAST(id as SIGNED /*UNSIGNED*/) LIKE '%1720%'
```